# Intellij won't automatically resolve npm local dependencies

Tags: node.js, npm, intellij-idea, dependencies

In my project for some reasons i'm using local npm dependencies like such in my `package.json`

```json
{
  "name": "my-super-project",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "dependencies": {
    ...
    "my-other-project": "file:../my-other-project",
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    ...
  },
}
```

All the building and serving part works all fine though during development, there is no autocompletion suggested by IntelliJ in fact, it may suggest the import but really hidden under the `More actions...`
[No direct suggestion](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sXdiq.png)
then when i click on it i have the suggestion i want.

Question being, why doesn't Intellij resolve my local dependencies as all other npm modules and suggest the import directly and how to possibly work around this or fix it ?
This is bringing confusion to the team when someone creates an element and someone else tries to importing, you have to write the exact name without Typo for intellij to suggest the appropriate import 3 clicks away within the usually unused because farfetched "more options".

I have tried digging through `Settings > Editor > General > Code Completion & Postfix Completion` without success, if someone has an idea would be greatly appreciated

Comment: please make sure that `node_modules/my-other-project` is not marked "excluded" in the **Project** tool window. Also, do you have you app stored in WSL by chance?

Comment: @lena It was indeed, thank you for this. And no i'm not using WSL. Now the import suggestion works but is all relative, my previous imports worked fine as `import {Order} from "my-other-project"`.
now the auto suggestion by default is `import {Order} from "my-other-project/dist/types/orders"` is there a way to configure it to simplify the default suggestion ? there is "index.ts" files in all of the libraries folders to basically export all so it's accessible from the root path